# Fit the scatter plot points within the frame in plotly

Tags: plotly

Why the bubbles inside the scatter plot goes outside of the frame during animation?How to fit the bubbles within the frame?

```
   fig = px.scatter(gm,x = 'gdpPercap',y = 'lifeExp',
    color='continent',
    facet_col_wrap=5,
    facet_col = 'continent',
    size = 'lifeExp',
    animation_frame="year",
    animation_group="continent",
    )
    fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way myself by adjusting the autoscale option on the top right corner of the chart!!

[image]